# rapaint(); repaint's immediately after drawing

Tags: java, swing

I'm  just starting out with JAVA and I'm trying to paint a image with an input.
I would like that the panel "refresh/reload" when a new value is given and the button "draw" is clicked.
i tryed all different ways of removeALL(); repaint(); an revalidate(); on different places.

with the removeAll(); the window freezes.
with only repaint(); and revalidate(); the image stays for only one seconds.

I want that the image stays until a new value is givin and the button is clicked.
down her is a part of the code. 
Thank you.

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
    Graphics paper = panel.getGraphics();

    String input = field.getText();
    String input2 =field2.getText(); 
    int x = Integer.parseInt(input);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(input2);

    paper.setColor(Color.red);
    paper.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);

    paper.setColor(Color.blue);
    paper.fillOval((x+100), y, 35, 35);

    paper.setColor(Color.blue);
    paper.fillOval(x, (y+100), 35, 35);

    paper.setColor(Color.black);
    paper.drawLine((x+49), (y+25), (x+102), (y+20));

    paper.setColor(Color.black);
    paper.drawLine((x+25), (y+49), (x+20), (y+102));

    //removeAll();
    //revalidate();
    //repaint();
}
```

I tried it in a different function:

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
    Graphics paper = panel.getGraphics();
    function(paper);
    repaint();
    revalidate();
}

public void function (Graphics paper){
.... }
```

didn't work..

Comment: Normally, you should redefine : `public void paint(Graphics g) {...}` and only call `repaint();` in your `actionPerformed(...)`

Comment: Override paintComponent() and use the Graphics object passed as a parameter rather than trying to paint within the ActionListener.

Comment: If you want to prepare an image offline, draw it to a BufferedImage, then draw that image in your panel's [paint(Graphics)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics)) method.

Answer (score 3):

Do not call panel.getGraphics() get it from the overridden paintComponents method. Like this:

```
public class MyJFrame extends JFrame {

    final JTextField field;
    final JTextField field2;
    final JButton btn;
    final MyJPanel panel;

    public MyJFrame() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        field = new JTextField("10");
        add(field);
        field2 = new JTextField("10");
        add(field2);
        btn = new JButton("paint");
        add(btn);
        panel = new MyJPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        add(panel);
        btn.addActionListener(e -> {
            panel.repaint();
        });
        pack();
    }

    class MyJPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics paper = g;
            String input = field.getText();
            String input2 = field2.getText();
            int x = Integer.parseInt(input);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(input2);

            paper.setColor(Color.red);
            paper.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);

            paper.setColor(Color.blue);
            paper.fillOval((x + 100), y, 35, 35);

            paper.setColor(Color.blue);
            paper.fillOval(x, (y + 100), 35, 35);

            paper.setColor(Color.black);
            paper.drawLine((x + 49), (y + 25), (x + 102), (y + 20));

            paper.setColor(Color.black);
            paper.drawLine((x + 25), (y + 49), (x + 20), (y + 102));
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new MyJFrame().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```